# PHP MYSQL Get data from database and echo message if no data retrieved

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to make a code where it displays all names in database where "clanwars" is set to 1 (int) and if all of them is 0 echo an message like: "Noone has signed up yet!"

This is some of the code i have:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE clanwars = 1 ORDER BY mantra");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if ($row['clanwars'] != '0') {
          echo $row['mantra']."<br>";
    } else {
        echo 'Noone has signed up yet!';
    }
    }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: And what is your specific problem? Isn't your code working or you want it to be improved?

Comment: You're explicitly selecting rows where clanwars is 1 so it can't be diffrent then 1 later in code.

Comment: try using mysqli_num_rows on that query to count the amount of rows where clanwars is 1, if it is zero rows, then no one matches that parameter.

Comment: So like this?
if (mysqli_num_rows($row['clanwars'] != '0')) {

Comment: No it doesn't work fedorqui

Answer (score 3):

First, in your example `row['clanwars']` will never equal to `0` because you already specified `WHERE clanwars = 1` in your query, so MySQL will return only those that have clanwars=1. If I understand well, you need to do something like:

```
<?
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE clanwars = 1 ORDER BY mantra");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) echo 'Noone has signed up yet';
  else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      //do what you need
    }
  }
?>
```

So basically, you retrieve everyone who has CLANWARS set to 1 in the database. If there are records, process them, if there are no records, it means that nobody has signed up.

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE clanwars = 1 ORDER BY mantra");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'Noone has signed up yet!';
}
else
{    
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo $row['mantra']."<br>";
   }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```